# WixSharp: create .msi at RunTime, not CompileTime

Tags: c#, wixsharp

Thanks in advance!

At the moment, my *.msi* is being built cat **Compile** time.

```
Compiler.BuildMsi(managedProject);
```

Is it possible to make so that the *.msi* is created at **Run** time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author of WixSharp gave a good answer here:
https://github.com/oleg-shilo/wixsharp/issues/136

> Just to clarify the "build process". Your Wix# project is a console application project. If its executable run then it invokes "main" and the msi is generated. The Wix# project template is configured in such a way that the exe is executed after every successful project compilation. This creates an effect of the "Compile build" but technically speaking it is a "Runtime build".